# How to simulate (or set up) localhost as a mining pool for XMRig miner?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, cpu-mining, mining-pool-setup

I am trying to run Xmrig miner to run without connecting to an online mining pool. Is it possible to simulate a mining pool (authentication and wallet) using localhost in windows? My goal is not to mine any real coins but to make Xmrig miner to run without wallet and online miner pool. I set up localhost and tried to run it with test username and password. But two things happened:

1. Huge pages are available but not enabled?
2. It says

> [localhost:80] JSON decode failed

[image]

Comment: So your trying to rewrite it to mine specific coins u want ...download the master files at git-hub and rework the program from there ..you'd have to change the mining algorithm and few other things ...if that what your doing let me know if you figure it out I'd be interested trying it out

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to install one of the XMRRig supported pools if you are wanting to test localhost.

For large page support, I believe you just need to run the app as an administrator. Information on the XMRRig project page https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig#huge-pages-unavailable